# Matching ID if more than one in column then nothing

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table1 and table2 
table1

```
nameID   column1  column2  column3
Joe      10       10       99
```

table2

```
nameID  column1  cost 
Joe      99       100
Joe      10       100
Joe      30       200
```

My goal to have column3 from table1 match with column1 from table2.
IF table2 **have 2 or more records** even if table1 column3 match with table2 column1 (99) and expect **nothing output**. 
IF table 2 have only one record on column1 (99) match with table1 column3 (99) then expect result

```
nameID   column3  cost
Joe      99         100
```

I have tried

```
select t1.name, t1.column3
from table1 t1 
join table2 t1 on t1.nameID = t2.nameID
where 
t1.column3 = t2.column1
and t1.column1 <> t2.column1
and t1.column2 <> t2.column1
```

Not sure how to make it works. Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify why you included logic referring to `column2` in your SQL?  Your question didn't mention `column2`.  Explain why you included this: `and t1.column2 <> t2.column1`

Comment: Can you clarify on this `IF table2 have 2 or more records even if table1 column3 match with table2 column1 (99) and expect nothing output.` Do you mean that when there are more than one record which matches with column 3 then you don't want anything in output?

Comment: sorry, column2 on table 2 <>  column1 on table2

Comment: And it should return record only when there is one matching record

Comment: correct. if more than 2 record then nothing output.  and return match only  it only one record match from 2 tables.

Comment: I'll try once more.  Your problems does not discuss `column2`, even though it's a column in the table.  Please change the question to include that detail.

Comment: @user13549459 added a new answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH CTE_X
AS (
    SELECT count(*) AS countX
    FROM table2 t2
    )
SELECT table1.nameId
    ,table1.column3
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column3 = table2.column1
JOIN CTE_X ON 1 = 1
WHERE CTE_X.countX = 1
```

Please see this

Comment: Ok let me try. TY

Comment: I don't now how to say thank you for your support. Thank you.